# Prevent JavaScript From Changing Page Styles

Tags: css, dojo, media

I am new to using javascript and CSS media queries and want to know if something is possible here.

I have a web page that has a script on it. I have a CSS file that is using a media query. When the media query css is being run,  I don't want the script to be able to change the css. I want the script to still work though because it is populating the menu. I just don't want it to change positions or background colors or any other styles. Is there a way to disable the script from changing css from the css file or from the html file? (I don't want to edit the script)

Comment: Don't include the script.. or change your IDs, classes and tags.  Otherwise you'll have to go through each one and use `!important` to disable each styling in your own style sheet.

Comment: I have to include the script. It populates the menu. But I can't change the script bc it is an included legacy script.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible. JavaScript can change anything on the page after it's loaded. You can disable JavaScript though. =))

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [`matchMedia`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453838.aspx) to determine which media query is currently being used. If a particular media query is working, you simply skip your JavaScript instructions. Otherwise, you proceed to modify the UI as you normally would.

With matchMedia you can also subscribe to media query changes so as to respond appropriately from your JavaScript. Consider checking out [Using Media Queries from Code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_media_queries_from_code) on MDN.

This option is mainly available in the [latest browsers](http://caniuse.com/matchmedia), but you can [polyfill it](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/) for older browsers as well.